# How do I change my code so that receive the correct answe

Tags: python

```py
def function(foo)
print(foo)
 
#Input:

Montag = 1
Dienstag = 2
Mittwoch = 3
Donnerstag = 4
Freitag = 5
Samstag = 6
Sonntag = 7 



Weekdays = eval(input("Bitte geben sie einen Wochentag ein: "))

Shift = input("Bitte zu verschiebende Tage angeben. Nur 1-7: ")

#process:

Result = Weekdays + Shift 


#output:

print("Das Ergebnis ist: ", Result)
```

[1]:

Create a Python 3.x program that accepts a day of the week, as well as a value that indicates the number of days to be shifted. As a result, the program should output the day of the week resulting from the shift.

that is the task. I really tried my best however,I'm just starting and got stuck on the last part.
My question is:
How do I have to change my code in order to receive the correct week day as an answer and not just the result of the equation; be it -2 or any other number?

Comment: Post code, not images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a function that can handle what you are asking

```py
def get_next_day(day, steps):
    days_of_the_week = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
    return days_of_the_week[days_of_the_week.index(day.lower()) + steps % 7]
```

Essentially what it is doing is taking the day and finding the index within a precreated list and then using the modulo operator it is locating the next steps required.

All you need is to parse correct input into the function using the input() function from python